# The property "Style" can only be set once

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I am trying to get [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17358030/2102827) to work, however I get the error `The property "Style" can only be set once.`. Why is that?

This is what I have:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SFVControls.Controls.Basic.BooleanRectangleView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="40">

    <StackPanel Name="stackTextPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,8,0,0" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding QuickDrawBarPinned}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,8,0,0" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding QuickDrawBarPinned}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,48,0,0" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks to this post and the answer, I was able to correct the bug in the original post you mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got two direct children of `<StackPanel.Style>`: A `Setter` for `Margin` that belongs within the `Style`, and the `Style` itself. You can only assign one thing to `<StackPanel.Style>`, and that thing has to be a `Style`.

So just move the `Margin` setter inside the `Style` element:

```
<StackPanel Name="stackTextPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">


            <!-- Gotta be inside the Style, not outside. -->
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,8,0,0" />


            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding QuickDrawBarPinned}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,8,0,0" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding QuickDrawBarPinned}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,48,0,0" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
</StackPanel>
```

In short, your style has a fashion *faux pas*.