# Updating property within Dependency property doesn't show within view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have a class, called Clan. A property within Clan is a bool Voiced, defaulting to false.

I have a view, ClanUI. This has a dependency Property of type Clan.

In the VM, I have a property of type Clan, which is passed into the view as a dependency property:

```
<UC:ClanUI Clan="{Binding Meilyr}" />
```

Within the ClanUI view, I have an image, which calls a command within the VM. It uses the correct DataContext:

```
...
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ClanVoiced, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Clan.Name}" />
...
```

In that command within the VM, I set the value of Voiced on the property Meilyr, which is passed into the view as a DP from false to true.

within the view, I have a datatrigger which should reflect a change in Voice.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Clan.Voiced}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I have tried starting with Voiced default to true, and this shows a border thickness of 2. So the binding is working correctly. I have debugged, and the code is hitting the VM correctly, and the Meilyr voiced property is being changed to true, and it is calling OnPropertyChanged correctly.

I have no idea why, when I change a value within the DP from the VM it doesn't reflect those changes within the view.

**EDIT:** Providing more code as requested

Here is the border and the image within the view. Clicking the image calls a command in the VM

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    ...
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" Margin="5">
        <Image Source="{Binding Clan.Image, FallbackValue='../Media/Clans/Meilyr.png'}" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ClanVoiced, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Clan.Name}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Image>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Clan.Voiced}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
    </Border>
    ...
</Grid>
```

And here is the Dependency Property in the xaml.cs:

```
public Clan Clan
    {
        get { return (Clan)GetValue(ClanProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClanProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClanProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Clan", typeof(Clan),
        typeof(ClanUI), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

in the Main View, here is how I place the view:

```
<UC:ClanUI Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Clan="{Binding Meilyr}" />
```

and here are some snippets from the VM:

```
private Clan _Meilyr = new Clan();
    public Clan Meilyr
    {
        get
        {
            return _Meilyr;
        }
        set
        {
            _Meilyr = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Meilyr");
        }
    }

...

private ICommand _ClanVoiced;
public ICommand ClanVoiced
{
    get
    {
        if (_ClanVoiced == null)
        {
            _ClanVoiced = new RelayCommand(ClanVoicedEx, null);
        }
        return _ClanVoiced;
    }
}
private void ClanVoicedEx(object p)
{
    if(Clans.FindAll(C => C.Voiced).Count >= 2)
    {
        //TODO
    }
    //Clans.First(C => C.Name == p.ToString()).Voiced = true; //<< This is how I will eventually be doing it, the next line was to ensure I was setting the correct thing.
    Meilyr.Voiced = true; //When debugging, when I click the image this line is hit, and after it has executed, inspecting Meilyr.Voiced shows it as being true.
}
```

Finally, here is the Voiced property within Clan.cs, as well as the OnPropertyChanged.

```
private bool _Voiced = false; //<< When I default this to true instead, it displays how I expect in the view. Initial bindings seem to work fine. It just doesn't seem to know when Voiced changes for some reason...
public bool Voiced
{
    get
    {
        return _Voiced;
    }
    set
    {
        _Voiced = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Voiced");
    }
}

...

#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        if (handler.Target is CollectionView)
        {
            ((CollectionView)handler.Target).Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

#endregion
```

Comment: Can you please show the code for the implemenation of ``Clan.Voiced``? Perhaps your implementation of OnPropertyChanged is not correct.

Comment: Are you setting the value of Voiced asynchronously? ie: Do you launch a thread to do some work and then set the value of ``Clan.Voiced`` when the job is done. Sometime you can get away with changes on a non ui thread. Sometimes you can't. Best advice is always to update view model properties on the UI thread.

Comment: Another idea. Do you set the border thickness explicitly on your control? I think this will override the setter in the style. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357117/datatrigger-binding-to-viewmodel-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `Clan` class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raises the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the Voiced property.

Since you are binding to the Clan.Voiced property it doesn't matter whether the view model class where the Meilyr and ClanVoided properties are defined implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: Just realised I forgot to add this code in, I added in the PropertyChanged and property for Voiced which I have to the original post. It should all be working as far as I can tell, but isnt.

Comment: Ohhhh.... I see it now. I hadn't put ': INotifyPropertyChanged' in... I feel stupid now.... EDIT - It works when I put this in... Of course... >.<

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the ViewModel code please.

I am assuming you are updating the Clan property changed but not the Voice property changed.  In other words, Voiced needs to be a property with it's own property changed event firing.

Comment: Updated with code. Voiced has its own onpropertychanged, and as a previous test (now taken out of code) I tried to call Onpropertychanged("Voiced") on the Clan instance manually from the VM when running the image clicked command but still nothing.